# Running a Python Class Method in a separate thread with args and kwargs

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a class A.

```
Class A():
    ....
```

It has a method B having an position argument c, and keyword argument d.

```
    def B(self, c, d=None):
        ....
```

Now, I want to run method B of an object `o = A()` with args `c1, d1`. I tried following:

```
t = thread.Thread(target=o.B, args=(c1,), kwargs={'d':d1})
t.start()
t.join()
```

but it doesn't work. Hence I also tried.

```
t = thread.Thread(target=A.B, args=(o, c1), kwargs={'d':d1})
t.start()
t.join()
```

This also doesn't work. The execution just falls through after `t.join()`. I set up the breakpoint in `Thread Class`'s first instruction in `threading module`, but code never reaches there.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What actually happens? Can you show runnable code that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Shouldn't 'self' be the first argument of B?

Comment: Beside other issues, you don't have self as first parameter of method B, thus you can't use it as instance method. And yes, "doesn't work" without error messages is wrong.

Comment: Sorry yes, self is indeed first argument to method B. I just edited it. Moreover, I gave an account of "doesn't work". Sorry for confusion.

Comment: `kwargs={d:d1}` should probably be `kwargs={"d":d1}`

Comment: yes it is 'd' .. again apologies for not writing that.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek post an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP*).

The problem was that in method `B()`, I was using `yield` statement. It was very surprising that on running the code, no exception was being generated, the interpreter simply didn't enter method `B()` and chose to skip it making it very hard to discover the bug.